# an exercise of linear programming written by katta g murty

Tags: linear-programming, independence, linear-independence

"let $D$ be a matrix that contains a row vector all the entries in which are zero, and let $E$ be the matrix obtained by deleting that zero row vector from $D$. prove that the set of column vectors of $D$ is linearly independent iff the set of column vectors of $E$ is linearly independent ."
source: excercise $3.8$ of the book called "linear programming murty" I tried but could not to solve it. I also searched by can't find manual solution file for the book that I mentioned.

Comment: can you include your partial working?

Comment: actually I have no ideas about it.. could you help me? or do you have the manual solutions of the book to share me?

Comment: not really. perhaps introduce some notations, and work from the definitions? after you attempt it, edit your post, and ask again.